# Can someone explain how the probability of a word at the beginning of a sentence is calculated?

Tags: nlp, n-gram

[image]

Hi everyone, I'm trying to calculate the probability of the sentence "I want Chinese food", which I succeeded in, but only because P(I|) has been noted own under the table. I can't seem to understand how the 0.25 is calculated. Can someone push me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you would have a dummy character for the beginning and end of a sentence, and you use that bigram to calculate the probability. I notice they are using `<s>`, as shown in the formula under the tables.

In the table itself this is omitted, so you cannot get it from there alone.

The sentence end is marked with `</s>`, so the probability that *food* is the final word in a sentence is 0.68 — though in a typical sentence that would be a full stop.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer! :) I still don't understand how the 0.68 or 0.25 is calculated. I think I'm missing something, but i don't know how to get the 0.68. Could you hint me how?

Comment: I think I should elaborte, sorry. I am trying to calculate the probability after laplace smoothing, so I figured I'd ask how this one is calculated in order to do the same with the laplace smoothing. My classmate just told me that the <s> and </s> values are the same as the ones without laplace smoothing, so still 0.68 and 0.25. Is this correct?

Comment: Don't know about smoothing, but you simply count the bigrams `<s> i`, and calculate the probability from that. You cannot do that from the table, as the data is not given.